# How to solve this 3-variables differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{ax}{x+y}z$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{by}{x+y}z$$
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=-(px+qy)$$
$$(a,\;b,\;p,\;q\;\;are\;constants)$$

(I'm not a native English speaker. So my English can be unnatural.)

Hello. I studied only basic differential equations.
However, I need to solve this equation above.
I would really appreciate it if you teach me the solution to this equation.
If there are no exact solutions, it's also good to get approximate solutions instead.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

From the first two,

$$b\frac{dx}x=a\frac{dy}y$$ gives

$$y=c x^{b/a}.$$

Then with $\alpha:=\dfrac ba-1$, we eliminate $y$,

$$\frac{dz}z=\frac xa(p+qcx^\alpha)(1+cx^\alpha)\,{dx}$$

and

$$z=d\exp\left(\frac{x^2}2\left(\frac{c^2qx^{2\alpha}}{\alpha+1}+\frac{2c(p+q)x^{\alpha}}{\alpha+2}+p\right)\right).$$

Finally, eliminating $z$, we get a nasty separable equation in $x,t$:

$${(1+cx^\alpha)}\,{\exp\left(-\dfrac{x^2}2\left(\dfrac{c^2qx^{2\alpha}}{\alpha+1}+\dfrac{2c(p+q)x^{\alpha}}{\alpha+2}+p\right)\right)}\,dx=-a d\,dt.$$